# whatsapp html link not working on iphone 8, chrome

Tags: html, ios, google-chrome, whatsapp

I have a html whatsapp link for users to share a website link via their whatsapp application.

I have used the following links to share:

**<a href="https://wa.me/?text=https%3a%2f%2fwww.youtube.com" target="_blank" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">**

or

**https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=&text=https%3a%2f%2fwww.youtube.com**

*Note that the shared links are already encoded

I understand that this link will automatically launch the whatsapp app if it is detected on their device, otherwise it would just redirect them to the app store.

However, I am only having an issue with **chrome** on **iPhone 8**.

The links work fine on other browsers (Safari, Firefox, Opera)

**IOS, Chrome & Whatsapp are all up to date.**

Even though whatsapp is installed on the device, it still redirects me to the app store.

the App store has a button which opens whatsapp, but the send shared link message window is not present. it just opens whatsapp like normal.

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think, as a temporary  fix at least, try making the link copy to the clipboard, then give the user an alert that it has happened. I'm not sure of how to fix it, as when I tested it it worked fine, but I'm using a slightly older version of iOS. Perhaps that means the new version made some changes about how this works?

Comment: Thanks, but I've already made a copy to clipboard link. I think this may be a compatibility issue as the problems seems to occur on recent iphone models with ios & apps up to date

Comment: @Steven I would think it was whatsapp, seeing the recent news. The app has just stopped functioning, and its looking to be a couple days until it's back up.

Answer (score 0):

First: [**Official Whatsapp Sharing Documentation**](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/).  Try one of the following formats...

> https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=YourShareTextHere
>
> https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=YourShareTextHere&phone=123

These seem to work for me!

If you are interested in watching a project that keeps track of these URLs, then check us out!: https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls#whatsapp

[image: Social Share URLs]